# How to make required filling in a form field with a many-to-many relationship in django admin

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Recipes model with an ingredients field with a many-to-many relationship. I have an intermediate Ingredient amount model associated with the ingredients field via through. I want to prohibit the creation of a recipe in django admin without ingredients. I'm trying to solve this problem by creating my own class inherited from BaseInlineFormSet and redefining the clean() method. It doesn't work out yet, I need help, what am I doing wrong?

admin.py

```
class IngredientsAmountInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean_ingredients(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data['ingredients']) < 1:
            return 'Укажите хотя бы один ингредиент в рецепте'
        return self.cleaned_data['ingredients']


class IngredientsAmountInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IngredientsAmount
    formset = IngredientsAmountInlineFormset
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Recipes)
class RecipesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'author', 'favorites_count',)
    list_filter = ('name', 'author', 'tags',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'author', 'tags',)
    empty_value_display = '-пусто-'
    inlines = (IngredientsAmountInline,)
```

models.py

```
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    measurement_unit = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...

class Recipes(models.Model):
...
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients,
                                         through='IngredientsAmount',
                                         related_name='recipes',
                                         verbose_name='Ингредиенты',
                                         )
...

class IngredientsAmount(models.Model):
    ingredients = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='amount',
                                    verbose_name='Ингредиенты',
                                    )
    recipes = models.ForeignKey(Recipes,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='amount',
                                verbose_name='Рецепты', )
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

obiviously clean should raise ValidationException:

```
class IngredientsAmountInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean_ingredients(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['ingredients']
        if value:
            return value    
        raise ValidationError(_('Укажите хотя бы один ингредиент в рецепте'))
```

by the way:
Try don't use the direct text message:

```
'Укажите хотя бы один ингредиент в рецепте'
```

Wrap your text in gettext/gettext_lazy, like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
_('Укажите хотя бы один ингредиент в рецепте')
```

It help you in future collect those messages together, and translate it if you need.